# what is python's road map to evolve

Tags: python, ruby

Where can I find the mid-term or long-term road map for python. By which, I can understand what the decision makers care the most and what the future of this language in their eyes?

I have been playing around with Python and Ruby by making small to middle sized tools I need in my development for a while, for fun and for learning by comparing different but similar languages.
Many of the features of Python and Ruby are interchangeable, or easy to mimic. Both imported some functional style and are evolving rapidly (Py3000 and Ruby 1.9). I'd like to know whether the two are going to get closer or diverge in the future.

I find some material for the road map of ruby, like
[Ruby Conference 2010](http://confreaks.net/videos/430-rubyconf2010-keynote-3)
, but where is the python's plan?

Thanks.

Comment: Some definition for "rapid" .... ^^

Comment: @eryksun your comment is worth an answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[PEP 0](http://www.python.org/dev/peps) lists accepted, open, and deferred proposals. See [PEP 398](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0398) for the 3.3 release schedule. Also, see Nick Coghlan's blog post "[Of Python and Road Maps (or the lack thereof)](http://www.boredomandlaziness.org/2011/08/of-python-and-road-maps-or-lack-thereof.html)".

Comment: Thank you @eryksun, the conference talk video in your link is what I am looking for.